# Group by values and other groups

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I need a help with the algorytm.

from the table

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| G1 | V1 |
| G1 | V2 |
| G2 | V1 |
| G2 | V3 |
| G3 | V4 |
| G4 | G2 |
| G4 | V5 |

I would like to get the group names with its values, in case group contains another group values from this group

G1=V1,V2

G2=V1,V3

G3=V4

G4=V1,V3,V5

I need to write it in python but it can be any language

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Is this a CSV table you need to read? Are you trying to group them in a certain data structure?

Comment: Consider some data manipulation packages, such as Pandas, which can go like: `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv'); df.groupby('Group')['Value'].agg(set)`.

Comment: After writing a version of code that does this (with some caveats), there are tradeoffs to each way you might write this. Is speed important? Is memory limited? How do you want to access this data once you've processed it? The example I provided should be modified to better fit your needs, if you provide more information it would be easier to create something that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example program in python that looks to do what you need!
Edit: I see I've misinterpreted. Will edit again and add group.
program.py

```
file = open("file.csv", "r")
class link_arr():
    def __init__(self):
        self.linked_groups = []
        self.values = []
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.values)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

output = {}
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if line == '':
        break
    words = line.split(',')
    words = [w.strip() for w in words]
    if not words[0] in output:
        output[words[0]] = link_arr()
    if words[1] in output:
        output[words[1]].linked_groups.append(words[0])
        for val in output[words[1]].values:
            output[words[0]].values.append(val)
    else:
        output[words[0]].values.append(words[1])
    for group in output[words[0]].linked_groups:
        output[group].values.append(words[1])
print(output)
```

file.csv

```
G1,V1
G1,V2
G2,V1
G2,V3
G3,V4
G4,G2
G4,V5
```

output:

```
{'G1': ['V1', 'V2'], 'G2': ['V1', 'V3'], 'G3': ['V4'], 'G4': ['V1', 'V3', 'V5']}
```

Comment: I think this will not work if the order of input data is different

Comment: This is true. It would be easy to fix this by running through the input data twice: Once  to get all the group names in the dictionary, and once more to populate them. I'll rewrite this to fix the issue.